# Getting "Can't Load Navigation because entity is not being tracked" Error when Running Unit Test

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to run a unit test (using **Moq**) that basically asserts that a new record was added to our test database.

The query below loads up a **User** entity and should load a navigation property on User that we'll call **EntityA**. The unit test eventually gets to a method that was written whose body contains this:

```
return context.Entry(this)
              .Collection(c => c.EntityA)
              .Query();
```

The **context** variable is passed into the method as an argument and is an instance of the **DbContext** we're using, and **this** represents a User.
When trying to run this specific code I get the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException : The navigation 'User.EntityA' cannot be loaded because the entity is not being tracked. Navigations can only be loaded for tracked entities.
```

This method has been here for quite some time, so I'm wondering if it's just the test that needs some explicit tracking property added (**.AsTracking** maybe?) to this query. I don't know why that wouldn't have been caught before as it's used in multiple high-visibility areas of our codebase. I'm open to any ideas for how to approach this one.

Comment: `Query()` (as any `IQueryable<T>` returning method) does not load anything - returns a query without executing it. It is executed later when some code enumerates it, which probably happens too late after the db context goes out of scope. You must force the execution/materialization of the query in this method, for instance adding `ToList()` at the end (after `Query()`).

Comment: Do you meant that the method runs fine in the application code but not in the test? If so, the question is: why is the user not attached in the test code?

Comment: @GertArnold That's what I was trying to figure out. This method runs in production code, and the same configurations are applied to the test DbContext used for testing except that I see now that we're calling UseInMemoryDatabase(dbName). Would this cause the lack of entity attachment?

Comment: No doubt it has something to do with Moq setup, but of course we see none of that. In general, if tests require EF to run just as in application code you shouldn't mock anything but run integration tests, preferably against the same db provider as the production environment.

Answer (score 2):

in my case, i removed this config from AddDbContext(),
if you really want to use this config. just use 2 dbcontexts

```
option.UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking);
```